# How to store evolution's folders on a usb disk

Tags: usb, mount, email, evolution

I'm trying to store evolution's folders on a USB stick.
I kill evolution and do as follows:

```
mv .config/evolution/ /media/user/evolution-backup/config/evolution
mv .local/share/evolution/ /media/user/evolution-backup/local/share/evolution
mv .cache/evolution/ /media/user/evolution-backup/cache/evolution
```

And then just link the folders:

```
ln -s /media/user/evolution-backup/config/evolution/ /home/user/.config/evolution/
ln -s /media/user/evolution-backup/local/share/evolution/ /home/user/.local/share/evolution/
ln -s /media/user/evolution-backup/cache/evolution/ /home/user/.cache/evolution/
```

This works as long as I don't restart my computer. I can open and close evolution and see my email and my email folders.

After a restart and with the USB disk mounted, I can see the links there, but if I start evolution it opens with the welcome screen, I cannot make it work.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but still I don't understand the problem. I think it has to do with when the USB pendrive gets mounted, if at system startup or when Gnome starts.

So I disabled Gnome automounting (info here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) by unticking the options under *org.gnome.desktop.media-handling* in dconf-editor.

Then I just added the entries to *fstab* to get the USB pendrive mounted at system startup (some info here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab).

Comment: Congratulations! As you auto-mount with `fstab` now, add the `nofail`-option to the `fstab` entry, this is helpful in the case the USB-stick is not connected to the machine during boot. Remind that if an `fstab`-entry fails, the system will probably not boot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should have got an error-message while creating the links.
You tried to create the links in directories which didn't exist any more, because you moved them to your USB stick. This should work:

```
ln -s /media/user/evolution-backup/config/evolution/ /home/user/.config/
ln -s /media/user/evolution-backup/local/share/evolution/ /home/user/.local/share/
ln -s /media/user/evolution-backup/cache/evolution/ /home/user/.cache/
```

or

```
ln -s /media/user/evolution-backup/config/evolution/ /home/user/.config/evolution
ln -s /media/user/evolution-backup/local/share/evolution/ /home/user/.local/share/evolution
ln -s /media/user/evolution-backup/cache/evolution/ /home/user/.cache/evolution
```

Take a look at `man ln`.

You have to make sure that the USB-stick is mounted at the same location as it was mounted while creating the links.

Comment: Hi, to me the second set of cmds look identical to the ones posted on the question... in any case, the links are not the problem, I can create them correctly. The problem is that if I reboot my pc, and after checking that the disk is mounted and the links correct, evolution ignores the links and tries to start from scratch (welcome screen to setup accounts).

Comment: @MartinMarco No, they are not same, you used a trailing slash at the end of the command! Gheck the mount-point with `mount | grep media`.

Comment: @MartinMarco If the mount-point is ok, I assume you created new `evolution`-folders and your links are now in `/home/user/.config/evolution/`, but they shoul be located in `/home/user/.config/evolution`, but then evolution wouldn't have worked correctly before you rebooted. So it's likely a problem with the mount-point.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think the links are ok and the disk is accessible. Could it be that evolution is checking for a directory (and it is finding a link instead) when it starts after a reboot?

Comment: @MartinMarco It should really work with links, I do the same with Thunderbird, my Thunderbird-profile is on a different Ext4-partition and the E-mails are stored on another NTFS-partition and it works. If your links are in the correct folders then you should try to add an entry in `/etc/fstab` to auto-mount the partition during start-up, probably that helps. I just see, I made a copy/paste-mistake in my last comment, the  links should be in `/home/user/.config/` and so on...

Comment: BTW, which file system type do you use on the USB-stick, FAT ? Probably better to use Ext2...

Comment: Hi, the links were OK, I think the problem was the mount order. Switched from Gnome automount to fstab and now I can have folders in the USB disk and still works after a reboot.